# Jenkins trigger a job by another by iterate through a list

Tags: jenkins

I have to jobs on jenkins, trigger and executor.

The trigger should iterating through a list and for each entry it should schedule a build of the executor job and pass the respective parameter

```
curl -X POST http://username:password@localhost:8080/job/executor/build --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"param", "value":"foo"}]}
```

Is it possible to iterate trough such an list and pass the entry as an parameter via curl?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do this with a Pipeline job.